# React Chartjs - Update Chart on interval

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, settimeout

I am trying to build an application that visually displays different sorting algorithms. I am using react and react-chartjs-2. The render and update work perfectly and I have no problem shuffling the data, then update the chart AFTER the algorithm is done running.

However, I can't seem to update it during the sorting. I am trying to update state whenever a swap occurs.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

export default class BarChart extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {
                labels: this.createLabels(),
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Bubble Sort',
                        data: this.createData(),
                        backgroundColor: this.createBg()
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }

    createData() {
        const data = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            data[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
        }

        return data;
    }

    createLabels() {
        const labels = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            labels[i] = `Label ${i}`;
        }

        return labels;
    }

    createBg() {
        const colors = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // generate colors
            const red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
            const green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
            const blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
            colors[i] = `rgba(${red}, ${green}, ${blue}, 0.5)`;
        }

        return colors;
    }

    update() {
        // create copy of dataset
        const datasetsCopy = this.state.data.datasets.slice(0);
        const dataCopy = datasetsCopy[0].data.slice(0);

        // update chartdata with random values
        for (let i = 0; i < dataCopy.length; i++) {
            dataCopy[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
        }

        // set copied updated dataset
        datasetsCopy[0].data = dataCopy;

        // update data state of chart
        this.setState({
            data: Object.assign({}, this.state.data, {
                datasets: datasetsCopy
            })
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.bubbleSort();
        }, 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timer)
    }

    bubbleSort() {

        // create copy of dataset
        const datasetsCopy = this.state.data.datasets.slice(0);
        const dataCopy = datasetsCopy[0].data.slice(0);

        // update chartdata with random values
        let temp1 = 0;
        let temp2 = 0;
        let timer = 100;
        for (let i = 0; i < dataCopy.length - 1; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < dataCopy.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (dataCopy[j] > dataCopy[j + 1]) {
                    timer += 100;
                    this.timer = setTimeout(
                        () => {

                            temp1 = dataCopy[j];
                            temp2 = dataCopy[j + 1];

                            // swap
                            dataCopy[j] = temp2;
                            dataCopy[j + 1] = temp1;

                            // set copied updated dataset
                            datasetsCopy[0].data = dataCopy;

                            // update data state of chart
                            this.setState({
                                data: Object.assign({}, this.state.data, {
                                    datasets: datasetsCopy
                                })
                            });
                        }
                        , timer
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Bar
                    data={this.state.data}
                    width={100}
                    height={500}
                    options={{
                        maintainAspectRatio: false
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about React but I know that [react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2) is a wrapper for [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/). When using Chart.js directly, the preferred method to [update a chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) is to invoke `chart.update()` once the chart data or its options have changed.

Therefore, in your code, your could do the same each time you want the chart be re-drawn on its `canvas`.

To do so, you first need to obtain a reference to the Chart.js instance as explained [here](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2#chartjs-instance).

```
constructor() {
  ... 
  this.chartReference = React.createRef(); 
  ...
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.chart = this.chartReference.current.chartInstance;
  ...
}

render() {
  return (
    <Bar
      ref={this.chartReference}
      ...
    />
  );
}
```

Your `bubbleSort` method could then be split into the following separate methods and it should work as expected.

```
bubbleSort() {
  let data = this.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
  let swapped;
  let timeout = 0;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i] > data[i + 1]) {
        let tmp = data[i];
        data[i] = data[i + 1];
        data[i + 1] = tmp;
        timeout += 100;
        this.updateChartDelayed(data.slice(0), timeout);
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
}

updateChartDelayed(data, timeout) {
  this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
    this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = data;
    this.chart.update();
  }, timeout);
}
```

Please take a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chartjs-2-bar-update-on-interval?file=index.js) and see how it works.