# Get access to the chart.js component instance in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I use `<Bar data={data} options={options}><Bar/>` for render. In options object I set legend onClick function but not able to get access to the chart instance. I should get access to instance since should get access to chart getDatasetMeta() method. Following instruction from documentation:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.3/configuration/legend.html

```
function(e, legendItem) {
    var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
    var ci = this.chart;
    var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);

    // See controller.isDatasetVisible comment
    meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !ci.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;

    // We hid a dataset ... rerender the chart
    ci.update();
}
```

Please advise if there is a way to access instance of Bar instead of creating it manually like this new Bar ().

Example:

```
function options() => ({
 legend: {
  onClick: function (e, legendItem){
   //Here I would like to set legend hidden  and some other things
  }
 }
});

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Bar data={data()} options={options()}><Bar/>
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly do you mean by getting instance of Bar, could you provide more code samples for clear understanding

Comment: @YatinGaikwad, description updated

Comment: @YatinGaikwad, In documentation they are updating chart instance referring to `this.chart.getDatasetMeta(legendItem.datasetIndex)`. But I don't have access to Bar instance context with this keyword.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302116/2358409

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to this issue in the wrapper you can put a ref on the bar component and that is the chart instance https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/3

```
<div className={classes.chartContainer}>
          <Line
            ref={myChartRef}
            data={chartData}
            options={options}
          />
        </div>

 const myChartRef = React.createRef();
  const handleResetZoom = () => {
    let chart = myChartRef.current.chartInstance;
    chart.resetZoom();
  };
```

Comment: thanks. saved my day. Also in ChartJS v3 it is referenced this way, if anybody else come across this.
const chart = chartRef.current;
chart.resetZoom();