# Update Chart using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, chart.js

I really struggle to find a solution and to even find if what I want to do is possible...

I have a react application that basically displays a chart (thanks to react-chartjs-2).

[Here is the basic content of my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efUFy.png). I successfully managed to delete the desired column thanks to labels[]. However by doing the same with data[], I manage to modify it (saw it by printing it) but it doesn't display on the chart. Is there a way to do this ? Easily ?

I thank everyone that has at least read my problem, I hope I'll find a solution soon... Thanks !

Comment: What do you expect for us to see what’s wrong here? from image of your data? :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302116/2358409

Comment: I have the exact same problem than this guy but the solution just avoids the problem by using Chart.js direcly :/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally found that I could manage what I wanted. By adding the "redraw" tag in the parameters of my  element and By setting a key=Date.now() in my initial state : so that every time I want to update my chart, I'll reset my key=Date.now() so that the state will understand that something has changed.